# Masking microdisplacement map

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, displacement

I have painted the area on plane where I would like to have one microdisplacement map and the the invert of that with no microdisplacement.

So white area is with microdisplacement map and black area without.

How should I connect the material to get that?

[image]

Comment: Sadly, the topology is not generated by any displacement map. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/Uf0VJdO.png) are two materials, one doesn't have displacement enabled and one with heavy displacement. All the subdivisions happen **before** the displacement through the subdivision modifier. As you can see both objects are dynamically-subdivided resulting in the same amount of vertices regardless of the actual displacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's essentially the same as you're doing to mix between shaders for your surface:

[image]

Here, I'm using the exact same texture to mix between shaders and to mix between displacement.  Since displacement doesn't use shaders, I'm using colors and a mix RGB node instead of a mix shader node, but it could as easily be done with values and math nodes:

[image]

Comment: thank you, is it possible to get the result with vertex colors ?

Comment: Yes, that would be a different question, but I doubt you need to ask it-- again, you're performing the same fundamental process, using a number provided from a texture in order to mix between two colors.